# How can I trigger Jenkins to build project by special string in comment of git commit?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

For example, I want to publish my project to a testing environment only when I put `<testing build>` string in the comment of a git commit.

Now, I have to do it using GitLab's web hooks and call Jenkins build URL once some code has been pushed. It does not make sense that only few code pushes trigger Jenkins build enough.

Comment: only when I put "testing build" string in comment of git commit.

Comment: After the job is triggered, in the section "Execute shell" run commands like `msg=$(git log -1 <commit> --pretty=%B);if [[ "$msg" =~ "testing build" ]];then #do the build;else echo "do nothing";fi`.

Comment: @ElpieKay 
Thanks, it's a good idea. But still has a build record in jenkins even if no any build actually.

Comment: I don't know any jenkins trigger that can filter commit messages, but some can filter branches. So you could make a branch for one commit and push it to trigger the build. The branch names follow a pattern. If the plugin can filter tags, it would be better.

Comment: @linuswang I edited your question to use single back ticks around your example string so that it shows

Comment: I have the same requirement. hope we can get some help.